# Using both interface builder and code to set autoresizingMask

Tags: interface-builder, autoresizingmask

I'm going through a book and one of the challenges are setting the autoresizingMask programmatically.
The only problem is I can't check if my code is correct because it seems like the setAutoresizingMask: gets overridden by what I set in the IB.

So actually two questions:

1) Is there any way to turn off autoresizingMask in IB? I removed all settings in IB and instead of the code taking over, it seems like Xcode interprets it as autoresizingMask set to default.

2) Are my codes correct? So here's what I did.

In the view controller file...

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
```

And then I made connection in IB from File Owner to Horizontal Slider and referred to "slider."
In the app delegate file I have the viewController set as rootViewController.

```
[viewController.slider setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

Still when I simulate and change orientation, the width of the slider doesn't change.

Thanks guys!

**** Actually it seems like my codes are wrong somehow... NSLogging autoresizingMask right after setting the code returns 0... Can't seem to figure out what's wrong..

Comment: It actually seems like the problem lies in the fact that I'm trying to access viewController's property slider from the AppDelegate file. Is this not allowed? I wasn't aware. When I put this setAuto.. method in -viewDidLoad it worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

You are using an obsolete tutorial. we use `NSAutolayoutConstraints` now ([adoption guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html)). you would be better served figuring out how to use that.

If you really do want to use `setAutoresizingMask:` then turn off autolayout in your nib first, or set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO on your views.